# Razor Page using Core 2.2 Localization not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, localization, razor-pages

I have a .NET Core 2.2 project

I have the following code in my startup

ConfigurationServices method

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

Configuration method

```
       app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("es-ES"),
        };
        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
            // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            // UI strings that we have localized.
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc();
```

I have in my Index Page.csHtml

```
 @page
 @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
 @model IndexModel
 @inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
 @{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Error";
 }
 <h3>Welcome to ASP.NET Localization</h3>
 <p>This is Localization</p>
 <h2>@Localizer["Overview"]</h2>
```

I am using the following methods in my Index.cshtml.cs

```
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<IndexModel> Localizer;
    public IndexModel(IStringLocalizer<IndexModel> localizer)
    {
        Localizer = localizer;
    }
```

I have created a Resource File

\Resources\Index.es.resx

This currently has a key for Overview.

I load the app and try to change the culture as

```
 https://localhost:44345/?culture=es-ES
```

But the string does not change as I would expect !

Comment: you need to change to language of the browser to make the code work

Comment: cool, but we want the user to be able to select ? eventually I need a drop down list !

Comment: then I think you can do reload the page so user will see the change

Comment: I am changing the url above by adding ?culture=es-ES to the url, but it doesnt change the language

Comment: I'm using the same functionality just like you and your code is not support language loading using url. I think you need to investigate how asp.net core handle language loading using url

Comment: Ill check out QueryStringRequestCultureProvider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using dotnet core2.1, the steps should be the same.

- create route culture provider:

```
public class RouteValueRequestCultureProvider : IRequestCultureProvider
    {
        private readonly CultureInfo[] _cultures;

        public RouteValueRequestCultureProvider(CultureInfo[] cultures)
        {
            _cultures = cultures;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// get {culture} route value from path string, 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="httpContext"></param>
        /// <returns>ProviderCultureResult depends on path {culture} route parameter, or default culture</returns>
        public Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var defaultCulture = "en";

            var path = httpContext.Request.Path;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(defaultCulture));
            }

            var routeValues = httpContext.Request.Path.Value.Split('/');
            if (routeValues.Count() <= 1)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(defaultCulture));
            }

            if (!_cultures.Any(x => x.Name.ToLower() == routeValues[1].ToLower()))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(defaultCulture));
            }

            return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(routeValues[1]));
        }
    }
```

- Add `RouteValueRequestCultureProvider` to the top of cultures providers list:

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(ops =>
            {
                ops.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
                ops.SupportedCultures = cultures.OrderBy(x=>x.EnglishName).ToList();
                ops.SupportedUICultures = cultures.OrderBy(x => x.EnglishName).ToList();

                // add RouteValueRequestCultureProvider to the beginning of the providers list. 
                ops.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, 
                    new RouteValueRequestCultureProvider(cultures));
            });
```

- Create a culture template for routing, so we get the url as:

  > http://mywebaddress.com/en-ES/

```
public class CultureTemplateRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
    {
        public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
        {
            var selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count;
            for (var i = 0; i < selectorCount; i++)
            {
                var selector = model.Selectors[i];
                model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
                {
                    AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                    {
                        Order = -1,
                        Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates(
                      "{culture?}",
                      selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template),
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

- configure services to use the culture route template:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(o => {
            o.Conventions.Add(new CultureTemplateRouteModelConvention());
        });
```

see full tutorial [here](http://ziyad.info/en/articles/10-Developing_Multicultural_Web_Application).

- for creating the language drop down, you can either create it manually as described [here](http://ziyad.info/en/articles/14-Creating_Language_Dropdown_Navigation) or you may use [this nugget package](http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/32-Language_Nav_TagHelper_for_ASP_NET_Core) to create it automatically with less code :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all

Answer (score 0):

Localizations for razor pages should be located in `Pages` folder. So localizations for `Index` razor page should be located at

```
\Resources\Pages\Index.es.resx
```

Answer (score 0):

With the linked tutorial you are using shared resources so you should not create a sub folder within Resources for Pages etc. but just name each resx file ViewResource.xx.resx.